# How to perform gradient descent on a keras neural network with two outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, gradienttape

I have a network that takes two inputs, the first input is passed through a series of convolutional layers, before being flattened and concatenated with the second input. The result is then passed through a number of dense layers. The second portion of this network is an actor critic network. So the network also has two outputs. I'm attempting to perform gradient descent given two distinct losses. One for the actor, one for the critic. However I'm running into the error: 'No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'co'...

The following learn function is responsible for performing the gradient descent:

```
def learn(self):
for _ in range(self.n_epochs):
    state_arr, additional_info, action_arr, old_prob_arr, values, reward_arr, _, trades_complete, env_states, batches = self.memory.generate_batches() 
    advantage = np.zeros(len(reward_arr), dtype=np.float32) 

    for t in range(len(reward_arr)-1): 
        a_t = 0 # advantage value at timestep t
        for k in range(t, len(reward_arr)-1):
            a_t += (reward_arr[k] + values[k+1] * (1-int(trades_complete[k])) - values[k])
        advantage[t] = a_t

    for batch in batches:
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            new_probs, new_val = self.cnn_actor_critic([state_arr[batch], additional_info[batch]])
            masked_new_probs = ENVIRONMENT.mass_apply_mask(new_probs.numpy(), env_states[batch])
            new_log_probs_of_old_actions = []
            for index, val in enumerate(masked_new_probs):
                new_log_probs_of_old_actions.append(-np.log(val[action_arr[batch][index]+1])) 
            new_log_probs_of_old_actions = np.array(new_log_probs_of_old_actions)
            new_val = new_val.numpy()
            critic_value = tf.squeeze(new_val, 1) 
            returns = advantage[batch] + values[batch]
            critic_loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE(critic_value, returns)
            prob_ratio = tf.math.exp(new_log_probs_of_old_actions - old_prob_arr)
            weighted_probs = advantage[batch] * prob_ratio
            clipped_probs = tf.clip_by_value(prob_ratio, 1-self.policy_clip, 1+self.policy_clip)
            weighted_clipped_probs = clipped_probs * advantage[batch]
            l_clip = tf.math.minimum(weighted_probs, weighted_clipped_probs) # prviously actor_loss
            entropy_term = - np.sum(np.multiply(new_log_probs_of_old_actions, np.log(new_log_probs_of_old_actions)))
            l_q_extension = self.c1*critic_loss.numpy()-self.c2*entropy_term
            l_q = -1*l_clip+l_q_extension
            actor_critic_cnn_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(l_q)
        cnn_actor_critic_params = self.cnn_actor_critic.trainable_weights
        actor_critic_grads = tape.gradient([actor_critic_cnn_loss, critic_loss], cnn_actor_critic_params)
        self.cnn_actor_critic.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_critic_grads, self.cnn_actor_critic.trainable_variables))
self.memory.clear_memory()
```

and it's the second last line raising the error:

```
self.cnn_actor_critic.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_critic_grads, self.cnn_actor_critic.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: You have some pieces of code missing, but in general: if you have numpy functions in your gradient calculations, the gradient will be lost, as numpy don't record gradients. Example would be: `entropy_term = - np.sum(np.multiply(new_log_probs_of_old_actions, np.log(new_log_probs_of_old_actions)))`. Exchange all your numpy function calls with tensorflow equivalents.